# Why my value for price turns to RM0.00 after update?

Tags: c#, asp.net

**This is my front-end code**

*I have tried to change from double to float and char but same thing happen. Even when I update
quantity, the price part change to 0.00 . How to fix this issue?*

```
<td><asp:Label ID="lblPPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PPrice","{0:c}")
 %>' ></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PPrice","
 {0:c}") %>' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox> </td>

             <td><asp:Label ID="lblPSelPrice" runat="server" Text='<%#
 Eval("PSelPrice","{0:c}") %>' ></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPSelPrice" runat="server" Text='<%#
 Eval("PSelPrice","{0:c}") %>' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox> </td>
```

**This is my code behind**

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PPrice", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =
double.TryParse(productPrice, out money);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PSelPrice", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value=
double.TryParse(productSelPrice, out money);
```

Comment: please don't use varchar for numeric values, thank you. also: look at The Manual for [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-5.0) and [AddWithValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) - what you're doing doesn't really make any sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

TryParse method returns bool value. Try assigning money variable.

```
if(double.TryParse(productPrice, out money))
{
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PPrice", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = money;
}
```